# Jar file execution through use of BAT file

Tags: java, jar, batch-file, executable-jar

I have created a simple class with only inherent Java dependencies (`java.io`, etc).
I have set up my jar file and the bat file in the same folder. The BAT simply reads:

```
java -jar "MyApp.jar"
pause
```

I have been able to run it from several different locations on my computer. But when I sent it to a coworker as a zip file, he was unable to run it by double clicking the BAT file.

The command window came back with an error

```
could not find the main class: MyApp.MyApp. Program will exit.
```

I've poked around this site but most similar errors involve use on the same computer.
Yes the other computer has Java installed 6.29

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  If so, the most 'idiot proof' way to supply it to others is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: `java -jar "MyApp.jar"`  Use `java -jar MyApp.jar` (no quotes).

Answer (score 3):

Two options that I can think off the top of my head:

1) He might not have extracted them both to the same directory (or) after extraction, he might have moved around the JAR file to another location.

2) His classpath does not include the current directory. Your classpath has a '.' (indicating the current directory) while his doesn't. If that is the case, you can probably modify your command to include the '-cp' switch.

Comment: The app doesn't have a GUI it just executes in the console window.

he had extracted them to the same directory, his desktop.

I used netbeans IDE to develop it if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a jar that way, you need a META-INF folder inside it with a manifest file inside that.  The manifest file needs a main-class line that points at your class with a main().    Your IDE probably added that, but maybe in the process of extracting things he unzipped the jar file too, or something "interesting" like that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: The issue ended up being a versioning problem. I was compiling in Java 7 they had Java 6 installed.
This was fixed by installing Java 6 from the Oracle archives. then setting up JDK1.6 as the Java Platform.

Comment: Additionally, you can configure your IDE or build scripts to target 1.6 on the class file format, even when you're building with Java 7.